# Using XOR to encode state

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

A sequence of bits encode the state of a game.

In order to encode subsequent game state changes the difference is encoded using XOR (to take advantage of an assumption that most game states will be closer to the starting state than not so to enable run-length encoding).

eg.

```
state 1:                         1000000000...
state 2:                         1000001000...
diff1 (XOR state 1 and state 2): 0000001000... => this is recorded
```

Using this diff, how do I get back to the actual current state (`state 2`)? Another XOR?

Comment: `state1 xor diff1 == state2`

Comment: Thank you. So XOR can be used to create bitmaps corresponding to diffs that are more amenable to run-length style compression? With a simple additional XOR enabling decoding?